# Flutter how to share PDF files?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, share

I'm trying to implement some new functionalities to my Flutter app such as sharing PDF files with people.
So I got 10 different pages and 10 different PDF files. On each page I want to implement a button, which then allows the user to share the specific PDF file (for example via WhatsApp, Mail, etc.). But I didn't find a proper solution. Where do I save those 10 PDF files inside of my Flutter project? And how can I implement this functionality in general?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

first you nee to get pdf in File so you can get path for share pdf

for sharing pdf used [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus)

after getting successfully path of pdf file in your local storage just follow the process

```
  File? x = await sharePdf(
                    url: widget.magazineModel.fileUrl,
                    fileName: widget.magazineModel.name,
                  );
```

above i get pdf from url and get reponse in form of bytes
(how to get from url not showing here)

next you do this

```
   if (x != null) {
                    await Share.shareXFiles(
                      [XFile(x.path)],
                      sharePositionOrigin: Rect.fromCircle(
                        radius: size.width * 0.25,
                        center: const Offset(0, 0),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Failed to share");
                  }
```

this way you can share pdf file

hope this will help you

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this package
It allows you to share all type of data to other apps.

https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus